# Flask Configuration for multiple instances. Best practices?

Tags: flask, configuration

In flask the configuration module is pretty-straight forward and there are ample best practices on the same topic from internet.

If I had to develop an Application which supports multiple instances, for example lets say there is a database for every city supported by application and every city db is independent MongoDB instance hosted on different physical machines.

A sample API code to support my example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class CityPopulation(Resource):
    def get(self, city_name):
        '''
        CODE TO GET CITY BASED DB Config
        Currently in JSON format
        '''
        total_population = helper_city(city_name)
        return { population : total_population }


api.add_resource(CityPopulation, '/<string:city_name>/population')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Currently what I've thought about is a json file with section for DB's as below

```
{
    db:[{
        'bengaluru' :{
            'host' : 'bengaluru.host.db'
            'port' : 27017,
            'user_name' : 'some_user',
            'password' : 'royalchallengers'
        },
        'hyderabad' :{
            'host' : 'hyderabad.host.db'
            'port' : 27017,
            'user_name' : 'some_user',
            'password' : 'sunrisers'
        }
    }]
}
```

and the class to read the configuration from JSON as

```
class project_config:
    def __init__(self):
        with open(config_full_path, 'r') as myfile:
            configuration_raw = json.load(myfile)
```

In Flask, the config module best practices was suggested as below

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True

class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = True
```

Is there a way for my scenario to be included the flask configuration and not to maintain a separate project configuration? In terms of best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The object based config in the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) is described an "an interesting pattern" but it's just one approach, not necessarily best practice.

You can update the contents of `app.config` in any way that makes sense for your use case. You could fetch values at run time from a service like etcd, zookeeper, or consul, or set them all via environment variables (a useful pattern with containerized apps), or load them from a config file like this.

```py
import os
import json
from flask import Flask
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

app = Flask(__name__)

def load_config():

    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(os.environ.get('MY_APP_CONFIG_FILE'))

    for k, v in config.items('my_app'):
        app.config[k] = v

@app.route('/')
def get_config():
        return json.dumps(dict(app.config), default=str)    

load_config()
```

And then run it like:

```
$ cat test.ini 
[my_app]
thing = stuff
other_thing = junk

$ MY_APP_CONFIG_FILE=test.ini FLASK_APP=test.py flask run

$ curl -s localhost:5000 | jq '.'
{
  "JSON_AS_ASCII": true,
  "USE_X_SENDFILE": false,
  "SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE": false,
  "SESSION_COOKIE_PATH": null,
  "SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN": null,
  "SESSION_COOKIE_NAME": "session",
  "LOGGER_HANDLER_POLICY": "always",
  "LOGGER_NAME": "test",
  "DEBUG": false,
  "SECRET_KEY": null,
  "EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING": false,
  "MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH": null,
  "APPLICATION_ROOT": null,
  "SERVER_NAME": null,
  "PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME": "http",
  "JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR": true,
  "TESTING": false,
  "PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME": "31 days, 0:00:00",
  "PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS": null,
  "TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD": null,
  "TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS": false,
  "thing": "stuff",                         <---
  "JSON_SORT_KEYS": true,
  "JSONIFY_MIMETYPE": "application/json",
  "SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY": true,
  "SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT": "12:00:00",
  "PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION": null,
  "other_thing": "junk",                    <---
  "SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST": true,
  "TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS": false
}
```

Comment: my point is if we have a 2/3 levels of object tree config such as "thing": {} or "thing": [{},{}] will this be still the best approach to keep a single big config file ?